# Dynamically set the color collectionview label background color

Tags: swift

I have the following implementation, which works it expected. I wonder how should I also deal with color of the corresponding label. For example, I want to set label color to blue for active, green for success and red for rejected

```
enum Status: Int, RawRepresentable, CustomStringConvertible {
  case active
  case success
  case rejected
  
  var description : String {
    switch self {
    case .active:
      return "Active"
    case .success:
      return "Success"
    case .rejected:
      return "Rejected"
    }
  }
}
```

**ClassCollectionViewCell.swift**

```
final class ClassCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {
  @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!
}
```

**ViewController**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ClassCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? ClassCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
  cell.statusLabel.text = classVM.getStatusText(atIndex: indexPath.row)
  return cell
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
func getStatusText(atIndex index: Int) -> String {
  return courses[index].status ?? ""
}
```

**Courses.swift**

```
struct Courses: Codable {
  let status: String?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would pass the `status` to your cell, and the cell would update itself accordingly. Since you are using ViewModels, you could introduce one for your cell as well. By doing the following, your cell does not know about the model, it's abstracted away inside the view model.

```swift
final class ClassCollectionCellViewModel {

    private let status: Status

    var text: String {
        status.description
    }

    var backgroundColor: UIColor {
        switch status {
        case .active:
            return .blue
        case .success:
            return .green
        case .rejected:
            return .red
        }
    }

    init(status: Status) {
        self.status = status
    }

}
```

Now let the cell to update itself accordingly to data from view model. You also may want to flush contents on `prepareForReuse()`. Now you can also make the subviews private.

```swift
final class ClassCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var statusLabel: UILabel!

    var viewModel: ClassCollectionCellViewModel? {
        didSet { update(with: viewMolde) }
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        viewModel = nil
    }

    private func update(with viewModel: ClassCollectionCellViewModel?) {
        statusLabel.text = viewModel?.text
        statusLabel.backgroundColor = viewModel?.backgroundColor ?? .clear
    }

}
```

And assign the cells viewModel from your main viewModel, where you initialise it.

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ClassCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? ClassCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
    cell.viewModel = classVM.getCellViewModel(atIndex: indexPath.row)
    return cell
}
```